# Is it possible to use collection of objects inside Django classes in python

Tags: python, django, oop

I am trying to implement the Finanace application with many classes (wrt java).
I have this case

```
class User {

String name;
Int age;
Collection<Accounts> accounts;
```

> Interface Account

Then following classes implements interface

> 1. Saving Account
> 2. Fixed Account
> 3. Insurance Account

The account will have User Object

As i am java person , i want to know can i use collection of Account objects in my user class.

Also how will Django handle the relationships and make database tables if i use collection

Comment: Are you trying to convert your Java-based application into a Django project? I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you should probably start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Actually i already have UML classes based on java and  now i have to code in python. I can manage other things but i only want to know that whether collection of objects can be stored in python class or not

Comment: Maybe you should start here instead: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `django.contrib.auth`, which already provides a `User` model, so you'll want to write a model to [store additional user information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users), instead of defining a new `User` model. Django models (generally) represent database tables, each attribute represents a database field. You define your models and their relationships, and Django provides a nice database-access API. You generally don't "store collection of Account objects", you create another model and use a `ForeignKey` field to describe the relationship between the models.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Account(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
```

And then you'd use Django's API to work with your models:

```
profile = User.objects.get(id=1).get_profile() # get user's profile
profile.account_set.all() # get all accounts associated with user's profile
acct = Account() # create a new account
profile.account_set.add(acct) # add a new account to the user's profile
```

[Django's tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) is a good place to start, if you want to use Django for this project you need some concept of how things are done. It's also might be a good idea to [learn python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) first.